# Is it possible to get the reference of a file in firebase storage with the download URI in React Native Firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

I'm storing an image in the firebase storage and I get the download URL once it is uploaded. Is it possible to get the reference of the image that I've uploaded using the download URL later?

I'm using Firebase in React Native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ***refFromURL*** method to get the reference.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Storage#reffromurl

```
const ref = await storage().refFromURL(url);
```